# Invalid Variant Operation error when access WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.getElementById('Inputname').setAttribute

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I am using `TWebBrowser` component in Delphi XE7 (win7, internet explorer 9) to fill a form in webpage.

Here is the HTML:

```html
<input name="login" class="form-control" id="inputLogin" placeholder="Username" type="text">
```

I am using this code:

```pascal
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.getElementById('InputLogin').setAttribute('value','sometext');
```

It works great on my PC, but on other PC it gives me this error:

`Invalid Variant Operation error.`

How can I fix this?

Comment: My guess would be that the other pc is missing a dll. It can be one of your own Delphi project or a MS dll required by the browser component. Does the other PC have a different browser version? -- Also, document.getElementById is case sensitive --> your ID is not with a capital 'Input....'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setAttribute` is not the preferred way to set/get the `value` for an `input` element.

use `IHTMLInputElement` interface to access the `value` of the target input element e.g.:

```
uses MSHTML;

var
  el: IHTMLElement;
  inputElement: IHTMLInputElement;

el := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument3).getElementById('inputLogin');
if Assigned(el) then
  if Supports(el, IID_IHTMLInputElement, inputElement) then
    inputElement.value := 'sometext';
```

I could not reproduce the error you got, so if you insist on using `setAttribute`, you might want to try to explicitly set the interface for the document instead of accessing `OleObject.Document` Variant.

e.g.:

```
el := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument3).getElementById('inputLogin');
if Assigned(el) then
  el.setAttribute('value', 'sometext', 0);
```

Comment: thank you kobik very much, it was very helpful, yes indeed using setattribut causing the issue of invalid variant (may the value is empty).  Thank you again, you save me  alot of time and effort.

Comment: You are welcome. if this answered your question please accept it. BTW, out of curiosity: Did the second approach via `el.setAttribute` worked for you on the other PC?

Comment: yes it does , it seem that the value of variant is always null for my first solution